# Elasticsearch simultaneously search by two documents

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have two different documents in the Elasticsearch - `Decision` and `Nomination`.

Right now I can only search all of the documents wit Decision type.

I use Spring Data Elasticsearch for this purpose:

```
PageRequest pageRequest = DecisionUtils.createPageRequest(pageNumber, pageSize);

MultiMatchQueryBuilder fuzzyMmQueryBuilder = multiMatchQuery(query, "name", "description").fuzziness("AUTO");
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder().should(fuzzyMmQueryBuilder);

NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
        nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withIndices(ESDecision.INDEX_NAME).withTypes(ESDecision.TYPE).withPageable(pageRequest);
NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = nativeSearchQueryBuilder.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder).withPageable(pageRequest).build();

return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(nativeSearchQuery, ESDecision.class);
```

Is it possible to update this code to search by `Decision` and `Nomination` simultaneously in order to get the search result from both of them ? If the answer is yes - please show an example how to implement this and also please show how to determine at search results who is Decision and who is Nomination ? Is there any classification field that can be added into search result entity for this purpose ?

Comment: yes, but in order to do so decision and nomination document has to be associated with each other. is there any relational association between them.

Comment: I use polyglot architecture at my project and at the ES level there is no association between them. But both of them are placed into the same index ad contain the similar fields - name and description.